# Redirect to file with no access rights. IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http

I need to redirect to files in my network when our users access one of our intranet page. Some users wont have access rights to some of the files. When this happens, IE opens up the parent folder which they have access to. 
Is there a way to make IE show an error message instead of opening the parent folder?

I'm using `window.location.href` to perform the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. This is a filesystem issue, not a browser issue.

Comment: Bummer... not even redirecting with a different technique?

Comment: It's not how you get there that's the problem. The rules reside at the destination.